# Change encoding of HTML error messages

Tags: php, php-5.5

I **maintain a legacy PHP project** that uses ISO-8859-15. When I get any kind of PHP error, the error message is not displayed at all whenever it contains a single non-ASCII character (most likely because modern PHP assumes UTF-8 everywhere). That happens in most custom exceptions because error messages are in Spanish:

[image: Fatal Error? Which one?]

Is there a PHP directive that controls this?

---

So far I'm disabling HTML errors as workaround. I don't need any kind of conversion because everything is correctly configured to use ISO-8859-15 (files, database, HTTP headers...). I'd say this is [sorted out in PHP/5.6](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) but I'm still at 5.5.

Comment: Ideally on any project you should have custom error and exception handlers registered anyway. You should never have to rely on the built-in error handling system. Fix your lack of proper error handling, and you fix your encoding problem ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol To be honest, getting uncaught exceptions and errors logged (production) or displayed with Xdebug (development) fulfils current needs: despite being legacy code, they're actually rare.

Comment: If you're in PHP5.5 why use ISO-8859-15? UTF-8 will solve all your issues.
On the concrete problem: maybe the browser is not recognizing the page as in that encoding? Do you send the right headers??

Comment: @BorislavSabev - 1) Because it's not an incoming project in design phase: it's a product that already exists. You don't demolish a building to fix a broken window. 2) Current encoding handling is fine. Trust me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to my initial believe, the builtin error handler does not seem to use the [`default_charset` directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) introduced in PHP/5.6.0 when composing HTML error messages, neither does it use `input_encoding` or `output_encoding`. So we're basically left with two alternatives:

1. Use a set of [custom error handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and [custom exception handler](http://php.net/set_exception_handler) (far from trivial if you don't want to end up with something worse than the original).
2. Disable HTML errors:

   ```
    if( version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '>=') ){
        ini_set('html_errors', false);
    }
   ```